# Report from SQL to Excel using user prompts

Tags: sql-server, excel, listbox, vba

I am pulling a report from SQL in Excel. I got it all working, except I need multiple user prompts (one parameter with multiple values).

I decided to use a listbox which contains all the possible selection that I want the user to choose from (These values are on another sheet in the same workbook) and then when a button is clicked, it displays the information in that same worksheet base on the selected choices the user choose.

This information that is being displayed is coming straight from SQL server.

I tried using a userform in VBA in Excel, but I am still not quite sure how to have it pull from SQL base on the selections in the listbox.

I had it where the information was displayed, except I was only able to input one parameter at a time. I want the user to be able to do multiple selections and then the information is displayed.

In my query I had wmav_code = ? to prompt the user to input what code they wanted, but as stated before, it generates a report base on that one value. I tried `wmav_code in (?,?,?,?)`, however, that's limiting the prompts to 4. I have 97 various codes to choose from (Hence the decision to use a listbox).

I tried `(InStr(?, [wmav_code])>0)`, but Excel 2016 does not recognize that function (`InStr()`).

P.S. These are all within the 'WHERE' clause.

I don't have to use a listbox, a simpler route/method would be appreciated.

Comment: "I got it all working" - without knowing *how* you're doing this, it's difficult to make useful suggestions.

Comment: Awesome! How did you get it working? For now, I am just using ' wmav_code in (?,?,?,?)' in the where clause after I made the connection to SQL server. So I am limited to four (4) prompts to the user.

Comment: I didn't do anything - that is a quote from your question and a request from me for you to explain how you "got it working".  There's are more than one way to get data from a database into Excel: it's difficult to suggest how to move forward if we don't know what you're doing. Bottom line though: there is no easy way to use parameters when you're performing an "in" query - you will need to construct the SQL according to the number of items the user selects, either hard-coding the values or adding one parameter per value.

Comment: Oh ok! I got you. I set the parameters, to display the information base on the user input in cells A2, A3, A4 and A5, hence why I am saying that I am limited to four (4). I would not want to hard code all 96 codes.

Comment: How *exactly* is my question here.  Are you using VBA ? ADO? How are you running this query?

Comment: I just realize that I didn't finish typing that reply. I am using a SQL query. I made the connection to the SQL server with the Get External Data (From Microsoft Query) selection under the data tab. I then created the connection and put my query in the SQL field. I returned the information back to Excel. I then added wmav_code (?,?,?,?) in the where clause to prompt the user from for inputs. These inputs are placed in A2, A3, A4 and A5 and the returned results is changed based on the inputted values.

Comment: The method I explained above is limiting me to user inputs of 4. I have a list of the codes that I would want the user choose from, instead of hard coding them into the parameter fields (which would be 96 parameters). Hence why I thought about going with a listbox with the codes, where the user can do multiple selections and the report is generated from those selections.

Comment: I think you'd find it easier to manage if you use ADO which will give you a lot more control (after a little initial learning curve) over how the query is run.  See for example: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/24677-connecting-to-a-sql-server-database-using-adodb/  That's for VB6 but VBA will be pretty much the same.